# How to run JSP files on Android and iOS browsers?

Tags: java, android, ios, iphone, jsp

I tried to run JSP files on my Android, but it is showing this message:

> Error loading the web page

How can I make it work on smartphones?

Answer (score 2):

I feel you can't run JSP pages on smartphones. Not only on smart phones and also in any normal browser without getting translated to html

Comment: So how can I translation it to html?

Comment: you cant do it manually JSP is dynamically generated web pages based on HTML, XML, or other document types. Any browser doesnt understand JAVA code

Comment: you can deploy that in server like tomcat etc and then call the URL from any desktop/mobile browser